# Values for which functions are undefined

Tags: functions

If a function is given by the rule $f(x) = x +1$ and we declare any three real numbers lets say, $2$, $3$, and $4$ as the permitted inputs or the domain of the function, then

$$f = \{(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)\}$$

but, if $x = 5$, then $f(5) = 6$. But $5$ is not in the domain of the function, then is the function undefined for $5$?

Comment: If you define the function to have domain $\{2,3,4\}$, then it clearly is not defined for $5$.

Comment: If the domain is $\{2,3,4\}$, then you are not allowed to plug in $5$.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to recall the definition of the domain of a function.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ isn't defined at $5$, all we can say is that if $x=5$, then $x+1=6$. But, for example, we might have a piecewise function that jumps to $f(x)=17$ for $x>4$, in which case $f(5)=17$.

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: @Clayton If $x = 5$, then $x + 1 = 6$ is it not equivalent of saying $f(5) = 6$ does it make any difference?

Comment: Samama: $f(x) = x+ 1$ if and only if $x\in \{2, 3, 4\}$. We don't know anything more about $f$, given your definition and restricted domain, so we can not say anything about $f(5)$...there is no rule for input of $5$.

Comment: @SamamaFahim: Functions are just rules assigned to numbers. If we pick a number that doesn't have a rule to it, we *can't* assume it obeys the same rule as some other numbers. That is why $f(5)$ need not equal $5+1$.

Comment: @Clayton I think we can't even say that $x = 5$, because its not in the domain. Can we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. The function, on the domain you defined, is undefined for $x  = 5$, since $5$ is not in the *domain* of the function.

Here, the domain of the function is all valid $x$ values: $x \in \{2, 3, 4\}$. The output for any given, which is  $f(x)$ corresponding to $x\mapsto f(x)$, then only makes sense for valid $x$ which are *in the domain of the function.*

If we define $f = \{(x, x + 1) \mid x \in \{2, 3, 4\}\}$, then yes, $f = \{(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5) \}$. Period. So the *range* of the function is $\{3, 4, 5\}$. If you want to expand the range of $f$, you need to expand the domain of $x$.

Comment: Can we also include an input that makes the output undefined? For example, can we include $x=0$ in the domain of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: In your case, @user599310, the function is undefined at $x=0$.  Your $f(x)= \frac 1x$ is defined only on the domain $[(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, +\infty)]\subset \mathbb R$

Comment: So when we say domain we can't throw in whatever we want. We must throw in inputs for which the function can produce outputs? But from wiki definition there is no such a statement. It says that the domain "is the set into which all of the input of the function is constrained to fall".

Comment: Exactly, @user599310, when we are speaking of the domain of a function.

Comment: e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$ (i.e. the domain of the function).  But the range is limited to all $f(x) \geq 0 \in \mathbb R$ for that same function.  Whereas, the domain of the function $f(x) = \sqrt x$, for $x \in \mathbb R$, is $[0, +\infty)$, which is also the range of $f(x) = \sqrt x.$

Comment: I can't understand why we can't let the domain to be all real numbers. We could say that the function is discontinuous without having to exclude inputs.

Comment: The function $f(x) = \sqrt x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ is simply *undefined* for $x \lt 0$.  We can only consider $f(x)= \sqrt x$ to be a function, if it is defined on it's entire domain.  Think of the domain of a function only the set of numbers on which the function is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111987/discussion-between-user599310-and-amwhy).

Answer (score 1):

That' right. If and only if $x$ is in the domain can we say $f(x)$ is defined on the value of $x$.